# Get the non 0 value for group ID in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to print only the IDs which have flag=1 but not have a group value as 0
(i.e print only flag = 1 in all visit)

Sample:

```
ID Val Flag
123 12 0
123 15 0
123 25 1
123 48 0
321 78 1
321 56 1
456 23 0
456 54 0
789 78 1
```

Expected Result:

```
ID 
321    
789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having min(flag)=max(flag) and min(flag)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
SELECT ID
FROM tablename
WHERE flag != 0
```